# Java Slick 2D get image pixel slow, any optimizations?

Tags: java, performance

In Java using the Slick 2D API, I built a game which takes in a bitmap as its world. If a bitmap’s pixel’s alpha is 0, it is considered air where the character is free to roam around; otherwise, it is solid and they cannot move through.

On my PC, I was running it at 1% of my CPU usage. Then when I tried running it on my laptop, it peaked its core and ran at 50% of my CPU usage.

After doing tests, I found out that the expansive function call was getting the image’s pixel `Image.getColor(x, y)`. Here is the interesting part. I rebuilt this same example in C++ using Allegro 5, and on my laptop it was running at 3% rather than 50%.

Are there more efficient ways to obtain a pixel from an Image in Slick 2D?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Image` object into an array of pixel values and get the values from the array. Excessive amounts of method calls will slow down your program significantly.

Comment: There seem to be no simple function to obtain the ImageBuffer from an Image. I would have to manually get the pixel, and fill my ImageBuffer, but doing so would make thousands more calls to getPixel then I currently am doing since I only ever call it 3 times per frame. I need to do this because during the game play, it is possible to modify the world by drawing, and then walking on the terrain that has been drawn.

Comment: @Johnathan: then Slick 2D is llaammee.  If you want to manipulate pixels in Java, the *only* efficient way is to directly manipulate each pixel as an ARGB *int*.  Anything else is suicide.  On OS X *getRGB* can be up to **three orders of magnitude** (that's right, 1 000 times) slower than reading that value directly from the backing *int[]*: measured on a Mac Mini.  Madness :(

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm simply going to forget making such an engine, sounds like too much trouble. I still wonder how they managed to pull it off in Wormux which is cross platform.

Comment: Could you update the array at the same time as you update the image, or would it be too hard to determine which pixels were drawn on.  Also instead of an int array, or could use a BitSet since you only care about transparent or not transparent.